# Why does my Intellisense for Unity in VS Code not work?

Tags: unity-game-engine, visual-studio-code, intellisense

I am trying to program in Unity using VS Code. However, I have noticed that when I start up my script from Unity, for about 5 seconds my Intellisense works. However, after that, it just stops. I tested by trying to type Rigidbody2D but it did not autocomplete. The highlighting also does not work. Here is a screenshot of what I am describing:
[screenshot of highlighting/Intellisense not working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Nvg9.png)
I have also taken a screenshot of what I believe to be the problem:
[what I believe to be the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JD9Ps.png)
I do not know how to fix this problem. Could someone please help me fix this because for a long time I have not had Intellisense in Visual Studio and so I tried switching to VS Code because I believe it is better but now I have this problem.

I tried to switch to VS Code for Intellisense to work, but it doesn't for some reason.

Comment: Well the good news is visual studio not working is all your set up and reliably works. Vs code not so much. Unity dropped support for it. It does work in code but an ant farting in nova scotia see s to upset it

Comment: what is an ant farting in nova scotia also ok i will destroy vs code

Answer (score 0):

Did you try "Regenerate project Files" in the External Tools configuration?

[image]